# Zero space between characters, decibel sign

Tags: spacing, formatting, letterspacing

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
dB
\end{document}
```

output,

[image]

But I want zero (maybe negative) space between d and B. That is

[image]

I didn't find duplicate another question. So, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean 'decibel': if so, this is an SI unit so should normally be just 'dB'. Do you have a reference showing the symbol in use?

Comment: `\newcommand*\decibel{\mbox{d\kern-.2emB}}`, and adjust `-.2em` to the length you want.

Comment: @Manuel `\mbox` doesn't look like a good choice here since it's doesn't use local font size.

Comment: My fault @Joseph Wright. Decibel, **egreg** always corrected my syntax, :). Joseph Wright, I don't want normally display. When I was very young I have seen this symbol in a book. Question [closed] for me, for now.

Comment: @tohecz You're probably right. Didn't remember that :)

Comment: It would be hard to decipher the kerned “dB”, as it appears much more like “oB”; apart from “d” being a prefix to the symbol “B” of the basic unit “bel”. In a logo the two serifs might be merged, but the stems should remain distinct.

Comment: For what is worth I usually use the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to typeset measurement units and numbers. I tried decibel and they're typeset exactly as "dB" written as plain text, as it should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sticking a "d" and "B" together sounds easy, but it actually required quite a bit of tuning.

EDITED to take egreg's suggestion of using a `\clipbox` instead of masking with a white `\rule`.

1) They are slightly different vertical height, so the "d" had to be scaled to the height of a "B".

2) The top serif of the "d" is sloping, and so part of the left side of the "B" had to be clipped for the "d" serif to make a smooth transition of the upper serif into the "B" (and to also remove the lower serif of the "B").

3) Finally, proper horizontal kerning had to be applied to the "B" so that the middle vertical stem wasn't too wide (from overlap).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\def\decibel{\scalerel{$d$\kern-1.4pt}{\clipbox{2pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{B}}}
\begin{document}
dB vs \decibel
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the package `trimclip` is better than painting white rules.

Comment: @egreg I don't find that package on CTAN.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It's part of the `adjustbox` suite by Martin Scharrer.